# Where midnight commander keeps ftp history?

Tags: midnight-commander

I've checked /etc/mc but It's not there, also not in config/mc/ini

The system is debian 9.9

Comment: Check  `~/.mc/`, and `~/.local/share/mc/`.

Comment: "mc does not have its own logs (you can enable it for ftp with the -l command line though) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in `~/.local/share/mc/history` under one of the sections. The section is `[inp:ftplink_cmd: FTP to machine ]` in my system, so I would use

```
awk '/ftplink/' RS="" ~/.local/share/mc/history
```

to fetch only the FTP history from that file.